# What are the X-StartTime and X-TimeStamp HTTP Header values?

Tags: http-headers, mjpeg

I am writing an HTTP proxy to serve up an [M-JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG) stream from an IP camera on the LAN.  I noticed that it returns the HTTP header `X-StartTime: 1276943417197`.  With each JPEG frame, it also includes a header like `X-TimeStamp: 346024130`.  I was unable to find anything about these headers online, does anybody know what they are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `X-StartTime` is the number of milliseconds elapsed since 1/1/1970, just like a Javascript Date...

`javascript:alert(new Date(1276943417197));`